# detect cryptography key generation/type with frida

Tags: java, android, cryptography, rsa, frida

I'm trying to understand how this particular app works.

At the start of registration, it will send two parameters named "keyA" and "keyB" to the server, and the server will reply with two parameters named "signe" and "data," and then the app will decrypt "data" using RSA/ECB/PKCS1.

Request:

```
{"keyA":"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAz8Hb9tbjtYAxNQi19h75CGBdsAuSCenn/t9p0DjLUOfh75qCvqJzkrE9gv6fXo1GcyMrfVAgRxjR37F3gOzilWVJiUk9VGq/1mGV/UXI8cK6Lkae+Zie3l5L1Qc0YjeBmkQiSjSkq3zo9AVgom473TFerQpcvukzqzQFN0k2sYBQWxpN3SDnpNSeiiHIEStw25WNPkSjQlrJB4RMiO2bKeBfTPjKFAG5/iSZVzRZ/P8fdv10m/D/F5AbIFgl4OXKzbLriAsBpmcXOPV3+LQ5OUfNgKFj1khs6JMo2GT5xMfAeIw4eqo77e7RSkQxocIg9ed4GNHvC9KDKXt6rBZJfQIDAQAB","keyB":"JhDGG3QVjn6Nosxg/kTfTR40MV1XetdZ2m/i314XFoUkA8f6Mgb/lQ38iVnEZpKULZ5y3ShnPa9lR1ZP/xhkttI9e0F67UTj/FNM2837qHMbNK7ZGtFCfuXfE6bokDci6eptIVIgsSL3Is9PFlc47g5E179jjeB8Bhtr4H+6CRoB5R+Ru82XfCI1xH45EbKVqEL+it2/NoiT0EzL892jKOd8qOMvrNxjRnl14TJrdY2KBsRzgVExSX03Bzg/+QLuMa1fBBPtONZjRSIBNK40z9rDBy9Ibdc1xBESWcZMZh2glPhaZe4oy3LQa8XFrEgKJolIMznA6UGdnVck0rXP9w=="}
```

Response:

```
{"signe":"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","data":"hzo3Y3biJ1+YKsmKL+pwiuBIUC332dEbV/ooy2ilb5yem5kF75fLKXCNjVdPUPZgQbx0wHTuQsjFgIIeabmUqzegKebxqtUOtDVIMEj54cmfJ1itDhZIJxivb42/x1LbBYuUi91hZy/xRx2opwA+gULMyJwbNlQlcp016KLCh9AiNFYtE77hSlbriO72G3ukD8s/7uMQfpdNcDwl7wWh4L4oIZCji3G/YPJW49CMvmsTnuUhK34E2ka1h9dfwMUvZT+CFEv/anC6gXktMzqmhI6enZB9bb33bwIBiF6k+MkI11Ea9wYdvlwVhbEvOLDYYt41L5UgTCBR5pH01MY06Q=="}
```

I can tell that keyA is an RSA public key (2048 bits) but I don't know what keyB is.

I've tried using https://codeshare.frida.re/@ensingerphilipp/frinja-crypto-fixed/ to see how these keys are being generated, but it doesn't show any key being generated.

I've tried the process multiple times and the result of my observations is that

1. KeyA and KeyB are somehow related, and if they don't match, the server replies with an error.
2. It can send different KeyB with the same KeyA.
3. If I send the same request multiple times, signe will not change, but the data will change (and I guess it's just because of padding).

My guess is that it's using another approach to generate these keys, but I'm not a Java developer.

I don't have access to these app source codes, and they're heavily obfuscated, so it's not an option to find anything from source codes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hard to tell given the information. I'd guess that it is a symmetric key or key seed encrypted with the public key of the server. It could also be a signature that can be evaluated with KeyA. That makes less sense to me, but you could try and do a raw public exponentiation the the modulus and exponent of the public key and see if it matches the PCKS#1 padding format. This is more something for [reverseengineering.se] but I'm not sure they would find the given information sufficient.

Comment: I see the app signing something :  Signature.getInstance called with algorithm: SHA256WithRSA, So I guess KeyB could be a signature, But I need to find out what is being signed here

Comment: The frida script you use seem to miss that keys can be loaded from `AndroidKeyStore` (and regular keystore files). Therefore I would recommend to hook all `java.security.KeyStore` `getInstance(...)` [methods](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore#getInstance(java.lang.String)) and [getKey](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore#getKey(java.lang.String,%20char[]))  method.

Answer (score 0):

I found some frida js code on a Chinese website and it helped me to dig more

KeyB is a singature and I was also able to see the string that was being signed with this code :

```
function showStacks2() {
        return;
        console.log(
            Java.use("android.util.Log")
            .getStackTraceString(
                Java.use("java.lang.Throwable").$new()
            )
        );
    }
    var ByteString = Java.use("com.android.okhttp.okio.ByteString");
    
    function toBase64(tag, data) {
        console.log(tag + " Base64: ", ByteString.of(data).base64());
    }
    
    function toHex(tag, data) {
        console.log(tag + " Hex: ", ByteString.of(data).hex());
    }
    
    function toUtf8(tag, data) {
        console.log(tag + " Utf8: ", ByteString.of(data).utf8());
    }
    var messageDigest = Java.use("java.security.MessageDigest");
    messageDigest.update.overload('byte').implementation = function(data) {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("MessageDigest.update('byte') is called!");
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.update(data);
    }
    messageDigest.update.overload('java.nio.ByteBuffer').implementation = function(data) {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("MessageDigest.update('java.nio.ByteBuffer') is called!");
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.update(data);
    }
    messageDigest.update.overload('[B').implementation = function(data) {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("MessageDigest.update('[B') is called!");
        var algorithm = this.getAlgorithm();
        var tag = algorithm + " update data";
        toUtf8(tag, data);
        toHex(tag, data);
        toBase64(tag, data);
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.update(data);
    }
    messageDigest.update.overload('[B', 'int', 'int').implementation = function(data, start, length) {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("MessageDigest.update('[B', 'int', 'int') is called!");
        var algorithm = this.getAlgorithm();
        var tag = algorithm + " update data";
        toUtf8(tag, data);
        toHex(tag, data);
        toBase64(tag, data);
        console.log("start:", start);
        console.log("length:", length);
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.update(data, start, length);
    }
    messageDigest.digest.overload().implementation = function() {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("MessageDigest.digest() is called!");
        var result = this.digest();
        var algorithm = this.getAlgorithm();
        var tag = algorithm + " digest result";
        toHex(tag, result);
        toBase64(tag, result);
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return result;
    }
    messageDigest.digest.overload('[B').implementation = function(data) {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("MessageDigest.digest('[B') is called!");
        var algorithm = this.getAlgorithm();
        var tag = algorithm + " digest data";
        toUtf8(tag, data);
        toHex(tag, data);
        toBase64(tag, data);
        var result = this.digest(data);
        var tags = algorithm + " digest result";
        toHex(tags, result);
        toBase64(tags, result);
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return result;
    }
    messageDigest.digest.overload('[B', 'int', 'int').implementation = function(data, start, length) {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("MessageDigest.digest('[B', 'int', 'int') is called!");
        var algorithm = this.getAlgorithm();
        var tag = algorithm + " digest data";
        toUtf8(tag, data);
        toHex(tag, data);
        toBase64(tag, data);
        var result = this.digest(data, start, length);
        var tags = algorithm + " digest result";
        toHex(tags, result);
        toBase64(tags, result);
        console.log("start:", start);
        console.log("length:", length);
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return result;
    }
    var mac = Java.use("javax.crypto.Mac");
    mac.init.overload('java.security.Key', 'java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec').implementation = function(key, AlgorithmParameterSpec) {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Mac.init('java.security.Key', 'java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec') is called!");
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.init(key, AlgorithmParameterSpec);
    }
    mac.init.overload('java.security.Key').implementation = function(key) {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Mac.init('java.security.Key') is called!");
        var algorithm = this.getAlgorithm();
        var tag = algorithm + " init Key";
        var keyBytes = key.getEncoded();
        toUtf8(tag, keyBytes);
        toHex(tag, keyBytes);
        toBase64(tag, keyBytes);
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.init(key);
    }
    mac.update.overload('byte').implementation = function(data) {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Mac.update('byte') is called!");
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.update(data);
    }
    mac.update.overload('java.nio.ByteBuffer').implementation = function(data) {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Mac.update('java.nio.ByteBuffer') is called!");
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.update(data);
    }
    mac.update.overload('[B').implementation = function(data) {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Mac.update('[B') is called!");
        var algorithm = this.getAlgorithm();
        var tag = algorithm + " update data";
        toUtf8(tag, data);
        toHex(tag, data);
        toBase64(tag, data);
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.update(data);
    }
    mac.update.overload('[B', 'int', 'int').implementation = function(data, start, length) {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Mac.update('[B', 'int', 'int') is called!");
        var algorithm = this.getAlgorithm();
        var tag = algorithm + " update data";
        toUtf8(tag, data);
        toHex(tag, data);
        toBase64(tag, data);
        console.log("start:", start);
        console.log("length:", length);
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.update(data, start, length);
    }
    mac.doFinal.overload().implementation = function() {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Mac.doFinal() is called!");
        var result = this.doFinal();
        var algorithm = this.getAlgorithm();
        var tag = algorithm + " doFinal result";
        toHex(tag, result);
        toBase64(tag, result);
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return result;
    }
    // DES/DESede/AES/RSA
    var cipher = Java.use("javax.crypto.Cipher");
    cipher.init.overload('int', 'java.security.cert.Certificate').implementation = function() {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Cipher.init('int', 'java.security.cert.Certificate') is called!");
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    cipher.init.overload('int', 'java.security.Key', 'java.security.SecureRandom').implementation = function() {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Cipher.init('int', 'java.security.Key', 'java.security.SecureRandom') is called!");
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    cipher.init.overload('int', 'java.security.cert.Certificate', 'java.security.SecureRandom').implementation = function() {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Cipher.init('int', 'java.security.cert.Certificate', 'java.security.SecureRandom') is called!");
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    cipher.init.overload('int', 'java.security.Key', 'java.security.AlgorithmParameters', 'java.security.SecureRandom').implementation = function() {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Cipher.init('int', 'java.security.Key', 'java.security.AlgorithmParameters', 'java.security.SecureRandom') is called!");
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    cipher.init.overload('int', 'java.security.Key', 'java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec', 'java.security.SecureRandom').implementation = function() {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Cipher.init('int', 'java.security.Key', 'java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec', 'java.security.SecureRandom') is called!");
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    cipher.init.overload('int', 'java.security.Key', 'java.security.AlgorithmParameters').implementation = function() {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Cipher.init('int', 'java.security.Key', 'java.security.AlgorithmParameters') is called!");
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    cipher.init.overload('int', 'java.security.Key').implementation = function() {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Cipher.init('int', 'java.security.Key') is called!");
        var algorithm = this.getAlgorithm();
        var tag = algorithm + " init Key";
        var className = JSON.stringify(arguments[1]);
        if (className.indexOf("OpenSSLRSAPrivateKey") === -1) {
            var keyBytes = arguments[1].getEncoded();
            toUtf8(tag, keyBytes);
            toHex(tag, keyBytes);
            toBase64(tag, keyBytes);
        }
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    cipher.init.overload('int', 'java.security.Key', 'java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec').implementation = function() {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Cipher.init('int', 'java.security.Key', 'java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec') is called!");
        var algorithm = this.getAlgorithm();
        var tag = algorithm + " init Key";
        var keyBytes = arguments[1].getEncoded();
        toUtf8(tag, keyBytes);
        toHex(tag, keyBytes);
        toBase64(tag, keyBytes);
        var tags = algorithm + " init iv";
        var iv = Java.cast(arguments[2], Java.use("javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec"));
        var ivBytes = iv.getIV();
        toUtf8(tags, ivBytes);
        toHex(tags, ivBytes);
        toBase64(tags, ivBytes);
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    cipher.doFinal.overload('java.nio.ByteBuffer', 'java.nio.ByteBuffer').implementation = function() {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Cipher.doFinal('java.nio.ByteBuffer', 'java.nio.ByteBuffer') is called!");
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.doFinal.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    cipher.doFinal.overload('[B', 'int').implementation = function() {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Cipher.doFinal('[B', 'int') is called!");
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.doFinal.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    cipher.doFinal.overload('[B', 'int', 'int', '[B').implementation = function() {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Cipher.doFinal('[B', 'int', 'int', '[B') is called!");
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.doFinal.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    cipher.doFinal.overload('[B', 'int', 'int', '[B', 'int').implementation = function() {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Cipher.doFinal('[B', 'int', 'int', '[B', 'int') is called!");
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.doFinal.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    cipher.doFinal.overload().implementation = function() {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Cipher.doFinal() is called!");
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.doFinal.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    cipher.doFinal.overload('[B').implementation = function() {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Cipher.doFinal('[B') is called!");
        var algorithm = this.getAlgorithm();
        var tag = algorithm + " doFinal data";
        var data = arguments[0];
        
        toBase64(tag, data);
        toHex(tag, data);
        toBase64(tag, data);
        var result = this.doFinal.apply(this, arguments);
        var tags = algorithm + " doFinal result";
        toHex(tags, result);
        toBase64(tags, result);
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return result;
    }
    cipher.doFinal.overload('[B', 'int', 'int').implementation = function() {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Cipher.doFinal('[B', 'int', 'int') is called!");
        var algorithm = this.getAlgorithm();
        var tag = algorithm + " doFinal data";
        var data = arguments[0];
        toUtf8(tag, data);
        toHex(tag, data);
        toBase64(tag, data);
        var result = this.doFinal.apply(this, arguments);
        var tags = algorithm + " doFinal result";
        toHex(tags, result);
        toBase64(tags, result);
        console.log("arguments[1]:", arguments[1], );
        console.log("arguments[2]:", arguments[2]);
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return result;
    }
    
    var signature = Java.use("java.security.Signature");
    signature.update.overload('byte').implementation = function(data) {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Signature.update('byte') is called!");
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.update(data);
    }
    signature.update.overload('java.nio.ByteBuffer').implementation = function(data) {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Signature.update('java.nio.ByteBuffer') is called!");
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.update(data);
    }
    signature.update.overload('[B', 'int', 'int').implementation = function(data, start, length) {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Signature.update('[B', 'int', 'int') is called!");
        var algorithm = this.getAlgorithm();
        var tag = algorithm + " update data";
        toUtf8(tag, data);
        toHex(tag, data);
        toBase64(tag, data);
        console.log("start:", start);
        console.log("length:", length);
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.update(data, start, length);
    }
    signature.sign.overload('[B', 'int', 'int').implementation = function() {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Signature.sign('[B', 'int', 'int') is called!");
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return this.sign.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    signature.sign.overload().implementation = function() {
        console.log("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓");
        console.log("Signature.sign() is called!");
        var result = this.sign();
        var algorithm = this.getAlgorithm();
        var tag = algorithm + " sign result";
        toHex(tag, result);
        toBase64(tag, result);
        showStacks2();
        console.log("↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑");
        return result;
    }
```

I was also able to simulate this process with my own generated key pairs.
When I decrypt response data it gives me some binary data that I don't know its purpose !! but it doesn't matter for now